# How do I change the platform branch when cloning an environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need help fixing a deprecated Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Python with Amazon Linux. Based on the information provided Amazon Linux is deprecated and I have to switch the platform to Amazon Linux 2. My Elastic Beanstalk status is severe and my web portal is not working.

See image insert.
[image: Elastic Beanstalk deprecated environment]

I tried to clone the platform and simply change to the recommended supported platform Amazon Linux2 however the option to switch is not provided as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Platform Branch disabled]

How do I get this done the easy way without having to do it from scratch?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get this done the easy way without having to do it from scratch?

You can't. It must be done **manually** as EB platforms based on AL2 are much different then those based on AL1. AWS provides a guide how to do it:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)